# Прогноз модели кредитного скоринга (классификация)

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Не так давно начал увлекаться библиотекой sklearn и всем что с ней связано. Решаю задачу по бинарной классификации. Разбил признаки(X) и цели(y) в отношении 70 на 30, на части для обучения и проверки. Затем обучил модель, после чего при проставлении прогнозируемого балла по всем этим признакам(X), оказывается, что поставленные баллы не находятся строго от 0 до 1, некоторым строчкам проставляется и 0 и 1 включительно.

Вопрос: нормально ли это, если нет, то с чем это связано? Модель вроде не переучил. Строил графики, смотрел, вроде все впорядке. Так же индекс Джини получился слишком большим. Очень важно знать, в чем дело.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

# создаю модель и обучаю
rf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=21, 
min_samples_leaf=1, max_features=25, random_state=42)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# создаю столбец со скоринговым баллом
prediction = rf.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]
print(min(prediction), max(prediction)) #печатает - 0.0 1.0


################################################################################



def plotting_Gini(targetcolumn, predictcolum):
    """функция построения Gini, на вход подаются 2 pd Series c изначальным результатом и тот который был предсказан"""
    actual = list(targetcolumn.values)
    predict = list(predictcolum.values)
    data = zip(actual, predict)
    sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda d: d[1], reverse=True)
    sorted_actual = [d[0] for d in sorted_data]

    cumulative_actual = np.cumsum(sorted_actual) / sum(actual)
    cumulative_index = np.arange(1, len(cumulative_actual) + 1) / len(predict)
    cumulative_actual_perfect = np.cumsum(sorted(actual, reverse=True)) / sum(actual)

    aucroc = roc_auc_score(actual, predict)
    gini = 2 * roc_auc_score(actual, predict) - 1
    fpr, tpr, t = roc_curve(actual, predict)
    x_values = [0] + list(cumulative_index)
    y_values = [0] + list(cumulative_actual)
    y_values_perfect = [0] + list(cumulative_actual_perfect)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharey=True, figsize=(18, 6))
    fig.suptitle('Gini = {:0.3f}\n\n'.format(gini), fontsize=26, fontweight='bold')

    f1, f2 = interp1d(x_values, y_values), interp1d(x_values, y_values_perfect)
    S_pred = quad(f1, 0, 1, points=x_values, limit=len(x_values))[0] - 0.5
    S_actual = quad(f2, 0, 1, points=x_values, limit=len(x_values))[0] - 0.5

    ax[0].plot([0] + fpr.tolist(), [0] + tpr.tolist(), lw=2, color='red')
    ax[0].plot([0] + fpr.tolist(), [0] + tpr.tolist(), lw=2, color='red')
    ax[0].fill_between([0] + fpr.tolist(), [0] + tpr.tolist(), color='red', alpha=0.1)
    ax[0].text(0.4, 0.2, 'S = {:0.3f}'.format(aucroc), fontsize=28)
    ax[1].plot(x_values, y_values, lw=2, color='blue')
    ax[1].fill_between(x_values, x_values, y_values, color='blue', alpha=0.1)
    ax[1].text(0.4, 0.2, 'S = {:0.3f}'.format(S_pred), fontsize=28)
    ax[2].plot(x_values, y_values_perfect, lw=2, color='green')
    ax[2].fill_between(x_values, x_values, y_values_perfect, color='green', alpha=0.1)
    ax[2].text(0.4, 0.2, 'S = {:0.3f}'.format(S_actual), fontsize=28)

    ax[0].set(title='ROC-AUC', xlabel='False Positive Rate',
              ylabel='True Positive Rate', xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
    ax[1].set(title='Gini')
    ax[2].set(title='Gini Perfect')
    for i in range(1, 3):
        ax[i].plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='black')
        ax[i].set(xlabel='Share of clients', ylabel='True Positive Rate', xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: А почему такое поведение вызывает вопросы? деревья решений спокойно могут и 0 и 1 выдавать

Comment: Я буквально с неделю этим начал заниматься, вот и хотел узнать нормально ли это. А индекс Джини то что такой большой выходит, это нормально? Возможно я как-то не правильно его считаю

Comment: укажите в вопросе код для расчета и отрисовки индекса Gini.

Comment: указал код в вопросе

Comment: Индекс GINI слишком высокий, скорее всего в данных есть target leak - что-то подмешалось, что почти 100% выдает целевую функцию, может сама целевая там

Comment: отбрасывание nan-значений это плохое решение. нужно заниматься нормализацией и проследить в каком именно моменте получаются таковые значения, возможно недоработка.